# Function returns null (returned value is not null) in PHP

Tags: php, function, return

I have been scratching my head over a function for a while now and was wondering if anyone could see what I'm doing wrong? I'm trying to return a value from a function but it is null, even though I know that the value I return isn't. Here's my function:

```
if (!function_exists('findTopLevel')){
    function findTopLevel($id){
        $DatabaseID = $id;

        echo json_encode($DatabaseID); //correct
        $parentID = $_SESSION['items'][$DatabaseID]['ParentID'];
        echo json_encode($parentID); //correct

        if($parentID == "top"){
            echo json_encode($DatabaseID); //correct
            return $DatabaseID; //returns null
        }

        else if($parentID !== "top"){
            ini_set('memory_limit', '-1'); 
            findTopLevel($parentID);
        }
    }
}
```

I call it here:

```
if(!strpos($HiddenPositionArray, $DatabaseID)){

        $topLevel = findTopLevel($DatabaseID);
        echo json_encode($topLevel); //says: null
    }
```

(I will not echo all these stuff when I know it works.)

What's wrong?

Comment: I think your missing a return before the recursion

Comment: @Philipp  don't really understand what you mean. I want to return the DatabaseID if its $parentID == "top" . Otherwise I want to call the function again to find the next parent.

Comment: He means `return findTopLevel($parentID);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are missing the `return` statement in the recursion part. So calling findTopLevel calls findTopLevel again, which returns the correct value, but the first call doesn't return the value.

```
function findTopLevel($id){
    $DatabaseID = $id;

    echo json_encode($DatabaseID);
    $parentID = $_SESSION['items'][$DatabaseID]['ParentID'];
    echo json_encode($parentID);

    if($parentID == "top") {
        echo json_encode($DatabaseID);
        return $DatabaseID;
    } else if($parentID !== "top") {
        ini_set('memory_limit', '-1'); 
        return findTopLevel($parentID); // The return here is important
    }
}
```

By the way, if you really need the `function_exists` part, you're doing something wrong.

Comment: I'll speculate that the `function_exists` is to protect against repeat `includes`, the solution being `include_once`.

Comment: Thank you so much, that did the trick! Exactly, @Flosculus. However include_once will not work for this specific file since it needs to run several times. I may transfer my functions to another document later on.